# Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations

Tags: c#, unity2d

tengo un problema con un código de movimiento en unity
este es el error:
Assets\Code\PlayerMove.cs(34,5): error CS8803: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.

Aquí está el código:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
      private float movimientoHorizontal = 0f;
        [SerializeField] private float velocidadDeMovimiento;

        [SerializeField] private float suavizadoDeMovimiento;

        private vector3 velocidad = Vector3.zero;

        private bool mirandoDerecha = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb2D = GetComponed<Rigidbody2D>();}
        private float movimientoHorizontal = 0f;
        [SerializeField] private float velocidadDeMovimiento;

        [SerializeField] private float suavizadoDeMovimiento;

        private vector3 velocidad = Vector3.zero;

        private bool mirandoDerecha = true;
        


    }

    void Update()
     {
    movimientoHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * velocidadDeMovimiento;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        mover(movimientoHorizontal * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
     


    void Mover(float mover)
    {
        Vector3 velocidadObjetivo = new Vector2(mover,rb2D.velocity.y);
        rb2D.velocity = Vector3.smoothDamp(rb2D.velocity,velocidadObjetivo, ref velocidad, suavizadoDeMovimiento);
        if(mover>0 && !mirandoDerecha)
        {
            //girar
            girar();
        }else if(mover<0&&mirandoDerecha)
        {
            //girar
            girar();
        }
    }
    void girar (){
        mirandoDerecha = !mirandoDerecha;
        vector3 escala = transform.localScale;
        escala.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = escala;
    }
```

esto es lo que me da problemas.

Comment: Coloca el código completo

Comment: no me deja hacerlo

Comment: ya lo hice amigo

Comment: Tienes unos corchetes que sobran  https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1AHP.png

Comment: se soluciono, pero ahora tengo el error Assets\Code\PlayerMove.cs(20,43): error CS1513: } expected